# window.load & $(document).ready() behaves differently with jQuery version 2 and 3

Tags: javascript, jquery

in this small project I tried to play with `window.load` and `$(document).ready()`

https://jsfiddle.net/23rupa07/

What I read was that `$(document).ready()` is triggered immediately when DOM is loaded and `window.load` is waiting until for example images are loaded.

For jQuery version 2.2.4 it's working as is mentioned above, but when I change jQuery to version 3.1.0 the order is reverted.

Check screenshot. Does anyone know why?
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## document ready change between jQuery2 and jQuery3

One of the changes of jQuery 3 is that as of now - the *document-ready* handlers are asynchronous, even if the document is currently ready at the point where the handler is added. This provides a consistent code execution order that is independent of whether the document is ready or not[[1]](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#breaking-change-document-ready-handlers-are-now-asynchronous).

This change required implementing a queue functionality for the document-ready callbacks, and this also affect other calls for events that are not called from the `jQuery` object.

If we take this code for example:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  console.log('vanilla - DOMContentLoaded');
});
$(function(){
  console.log('jquery - DOM loaded');
});
```

**jQuery2** will give us:

```
jquery - DOM loaded
vanilla - DOMContentLoaded
```

**jQuery3** will give us:

```
vanilla - DOMContentLoaded
jquery - DOM loaded
```

The behavior we see in the OP is related to a race-condition between the "fire" event of the document-ready's callbacks and the `window.onload` function.

This code will can show that the two functions run "at the same time", and it's only a matter of code-execution inside the VM of the browser:

```js
$(function(){
    console.log('jquery - DOM loaded')
});

window.onload = function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('window - loaded');
    }, 0);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```

Regarding the question about the images - since the images are already in your cache when you load the document, it only seems like the `window.onload` function is called *before* the `document.ready` (it's a race condition), however if you will make sure the images will never cache - you will see that you get exactly the same results for both jquery2 and jquery3.

### jQuery 2

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  console.log('jquery - DOM loaded');
});

window.onload = function(){
  console.log('window - loaded');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    
    document.writeln('<img src="https://o.aolcdn.com/commerce/autodata/images/USC60LGC051A021001.jpg?'+ parseInt(Math.random()*10000) +'" alt="">');
  }
</script>
```

## jQuery 3

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  console.log('jquery - DOM loaded');
});

window.onload = function(){
  console.log('window - loaded');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    
    document.writeln('<img src="https://o.aolcdn.com/commerce/autodata/images/USC60LGC051A021001.jpg?'+ parseInt(Math.random()*10000) +'" alt="">');
  }
</script>
```

Comment: As (Bhojendra Nepal) said it is interesting that version 1 & 2 has same behavior but version 3 not. But I agree that images are probably cached.

Comment: @tonco, actually there is a change. You can keep (or remove) the "accepted" on my answer, I'm still in the middle of debugging/investigation and will update the answer soon :)

Comment: @BhojendraNepal, answer updated, you can check now :)

Comment: great this make more sense