# Does $(document).ready() behave differently in v2 compared to v3 when the browser back button is invoked?

Tags: jquery

I have a page with a typical `<FORM>` whose fields are empty when the page is loaded.

If the user clicks the browser back button after submitting the form, the page shows the fields **as filled in by the user**. However, any attempt to read these fields in the `$document.ready()` callback returns empty values. This is for jQuery v2.

With v3, it appears to be working correctly.

I would like to confirm if this a known difference before I budget the effort to test and migrate to v3 for an existing production website.

**jQuery v2:**

```js
window.addEventListener("load", ()=> {
  console.log("! textbox:", document.getElementById("textbox").value);
});
$(document).ready(() => {
  console.log("$ textbox:", document.getElementById("textbox").value);
});
```

```html
<p>1. Enter something in the textbox and click Submit. 2. Click the browser back button. 3. Check console log.</p>

<form method="post">
  <input id='textbox' required />
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>

<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

**jQuery v3:**

```js
window.addEventListener("load", ()=> {
  console.log("! textbox:", document.getElementById("textbox").value);
});
$(document).ready(() => {
  console.log("$ textbox:", document.getElementById("textbox").value);
});
```

```html
<p>1. Enter something in the textbox and click Submit. 2. Click the browser back button. 3. Check console log.</p>

<form method="post">
  <input id='textbox' required />
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your snippet does prove the difference in behaviour, however I'm not aware of any specific action taken to affect this behaviour. More likely it's a corollary of another pull request - although I haven't checked all the change logs from 2.2.4 to 3.6.0 (and I feel sorry for anyone who needs to!)

Comment: If absolutely need to pin down the cause, Github lets you compare branches, although it truncates to the most recent 250 commits: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/compare/2.2.4...3.5.0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [window.load & $(document).ready() behaves differently with jQuery version 2 and 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39571914/window-load-document-ready-behaves-differently-with-jquery-version-2-and)

Comment: @PeterKrebs That question was about the order of execution. I have updated my question to show v2 and v3 separately, and it shows the same order of execution as demonstrated in that question. At `window.load` the user written values cannot be found in both jQuery versions. `$(document).ready()` v3 is able to read the user written values.

Comment: I am now quite confused over what the DOM is or is not. My page has an original DOM that is updated by user input. The page unloads (on user clicking Submit) and then is loaded back (when user hits back arrow on browser) from the cache I believe. There is not much information on what happens when the DOM is rebuilt in this situation. What I need now is whether v3 will consistently be able to read the the *modified* DOM or is there another way to reliably get it.

Comment: Is this behaviour consistent with all modern browsers?

Comment: @OldGeezer The answer says *One of the changes of jQuery 3 is that as of now - the document-ready handlers are asynchronous,* ... shouldn't this have an impact between the versions? The back-button problem is maybe a symtom of the same change.

Comment: @Huangism earlier I had only been testing on Chrome 91. Now that you mention it, running the above snippets on Edge produces slightly different results. v2: `$ textbox: ! textbox: xxx`, v3: `$ textbox: xxx ! textbox: xxx`, where xxx is the text entered in the text box. So jQuery v2 works in Edge.